# Jmeter e commerce, "Order is not added into my account"

Tags: performance, jmeter, e-commerce

I have written a load script for e-commerce site, when executing the same from Jmeter it's working fine without any error. But on other side i checked my order list from web there is no such order history created. Cookie manager, Cache manager, CSV config all the necessary parameter used.
So Jmeter only verify server response or really push the data into DB. If Yes, please help me to understand this issue.

Same created the script for bulk account creation, getting the server response 200. But accounts are not added into DB.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KliV.png)

Answer (score 1):

JMeter automatically treats [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful, it doesn't do any checking of response data. If you have HTTP Response Code 200 JMeter will consider the request successful.

Prior to running a load test with large number of virtual users I would recommend running it in GUI mode with 1-2 virtual users/loop to ensure that it does what it is supposed to be doing by checking requests and responses details in [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. My expectation is that your scenario doesn't simply go further than the login page due to one of the following potential problems:

- Missing or improperly working [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations)
- Missing [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
- HTTP Requests are not inline with the ones which are sent by real browser, i.e. missing headers, bad format of data, etc.

So given you send identical requests by browser and JMeter (assuming proper correlation of dynamic parameters) you should be getting identical responses.

Comment: Image attached for reference please check